# Angular Typescript On Array.map is returning ""this.array.map is not a function"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using Angular 6 and previous got this following to work get all the values associated with an array property

```
this.object.array.map(item => item.month).filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index);
```

In another component, the webservice is returning an array and not an object with an embedded array. The following is throwing map() is not a function which is confusing.

```
this.array.map(item => item.month).filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index);
```

Here is the model definition of the array

In my ts code, I declared as following

```
 myArrays: ArrayType[];
```

in my model.ts

```
export class ArrayType {

  constructor () {


  }
  public id: string;
  public name: string;
  public month: string;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: so the array in the object is named `array`, right? gotta ask, since you haven't provided how your data looks like... you should provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need check the returned object from your webservice is array or not.

I tried to reproduce your code still worked.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-array-map2